# Force onDestroyView on a fragment's view

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-management, android-lifecycle, ondestroy

I'm writing an app that loads user profiles and user's ratings for different places. The app uses fragments pervasively, and it's relatively easy to jump from a profile to a rated place.

As a user clicks a profile and gets to a rated place, they can click another profile on a rated place and go on and on.

The problem I'm having is memory related, when I'm looking at a ranked place and I click a profile, I switch from one Activity to the next. In both of these activities, after setContentView I load a fragment dynamically into layout space.

Now, as I shuttle between these activities, onSaveInstance state is almost always called, however since the Fragment displaying whatever was in the foreground before the activity switch, onDestroyView is not called.

What I would like is when onSaveInstanceState is called in these dynamic fragments, it to force onDestroyView to be called as well.

The only time onDestroyView seems to be called is when I add a Fragment to the back stack. When another activity comes to the foreground and this fragment is stopped, I'd like on DestroyView to be called as well.

The current workaround I want to implement is have an empty fragment with no view, and every time I call startActivity(Intent i), load this dummy fragment to destroy views and start the next activity. Then, when I come back, pop it off the back stack and restore the actual last fragment.

This however seems excessive. So, for a stopped fragment in a stopped activity with a new activity in front of it, how do I force it to destroy it's View?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not force or satisfy `onDestroyView` to fix your code, that's the job of the FragmentManager and the Android lifecyle @ [Pausing and Resuming an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html). If you want to work with your existing code, use the other override methods `onPause`() or `onStop`().

Without posted code, I assume you're using the replace() method to display one fragment over another. This more or less forces you to manage the fragments yourself, some developers actually succeed in doing so with some struggle (look at other SO questions).
So my suggestion for you is either:

- Maintain your own states, and show the proper fragments based on the state.
- Use the **BackStack** and let the Fragment management handle the stack/states.

Comment: I do use the replace method, and I do manage the fragments myself with little issue.

I just tried my DummyFragment workaround and it helps, but only slightly so. It appears my memory management issue has little to do with undestroyed views and more with how I manage resources.

Comment: This is off topic on this question, but related to memory management which is one of the tags. I get a lot of OOM Errors, and using MAT, I'm certain it's not a memory leak. The biggest culprits are byte arrays which is from loading images.

I use a RecylcerView for all images and Picasso to do all loading. Am I supposed to do clean up anywhere? I assume Picasso does all that? Or is there anywhere I need to call ImageView.setImageDrawable(null)?

I'm very much a beginner and any help or pointers would be much appreciated.